R installation issue - no package called bspm
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a remote server.  Recently I tried to install R it seemed to go without any errors, using sudo apt install r-base-core.   However, on starting R, it says there is no package called 'bspm'.  Attempting to install 'bspm' within R using install.packages('bspm') simply results in the same error message.
The OS version is: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1018-aws x86_64)
The installed R version is R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24) -- "Puppy Cup"
Googling on the problem landed me on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bspm/readme/README.html#ubuntu.
I followed the instructions for Ubuntu, with following result, from within R:
>install.packages("bspm", repos="https://cran.r-project.org")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/bspm_0.5.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 27097 bytes (26 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 26 KB

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘bspm’
Calls: suppressMessages ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpfrsQzD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("bspm", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘bspm’ had non-zero exit status

so it seems to be saying bspm could not be loaded because there is no package called bspm!
Output from .libPaths() is:
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
>

Any help on how to solve this would be much appreciated.  Normally R installation on Ubuntu is very straightforward, but I note this R 4.4.0 version is recent (2024-04-24) so maybe there is an incompatibility with Ubuntu 22.04 and I should install an older version?  Any ideas or info would be much appreciated.

I've tried to reproduce this and can't - can you see the downloaded bspm_0.5.7.tar.gz in the /tmp/RtmpfrsQzD/downloaded_packages/ directory? Do you get any more helpful information if you add verbose=TRUE to the install.packages command?

I had the same problem and got the solution in this post

Try
sudo apt install r-cran-bspm

This only worked on one machine. The others, I had to compile R from source, then the rest falls into place. Try compling from source.

I got around this by install r2u - https://github.com/eddelbuettel/r2u
